# Can't install .NET framework because Windows thinks newer version is installed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I'm using `visual studio community` 2017 on `Windows 10`. It crashed before and I had to delete some registry entries to be able to reinstall it. Today I needed to run a project on `.NET 4.6.1 and it won't install it`.

I tried o install it via visual studio installer -> individual components (uninstall/install) and to download from microsoft website. In first scenario no changes, in second scenario it says that a newer version is already installed.

I checked `HKLM -> Software -> WOW6432Node -> Microsoft -> NET Framework Setup -> NDP -> v4 -> Full -> version is 4.7.03056` and `HKLM -> Microsoft -> NET Framework Setup -> NDP -> v4 -> Full -> version is 4.7.03056` too.

In `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` I have installed `only .net 4.5.1` . I guess I need to delete something in registry so it won't think that newer version is installed.

Note: I can install .net 4.6.2+ through visual studio installer.

Comment: Windows is perfectly right. A newer version *is* installed, Windows 10 comes with 4.7.x. The latest update installed 4.7.2

Comment: Besides, you *don't* need to install .NET 4.6.1. *All* versions after 4.0 are binary replacements of the previous one. If you want to *target* 4.6.1 just change the target framework in your project's properties

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos , But I don't see .net 4.7 in `Programs and Features`. P.S. I understand, I just have a list of projects in 4.6.1 and that will require to manually change target framework for all. I posted question so I understand the reason.

Answer (score 9):

Windows 10 ships with the 4.7.x version of the .NET Framework. It's an in-place update of .NET 4.0.

But you can [install the Developer Pack for older versions of the .NET Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks). This will allow you to build against specific versions of the framework. In Windows 10 the applications will run in Framework 4.7.2 though.

This will allow you to build applications for older versions of the framework and different versions of Windows.

Comment: I have the same problema but with Windows 10 ver 1809,  my VS don't see the framework 4.7.2, and when I tryed to install it, the installer says  that I haver a newer versión..... any help with this Will be great, thankss

Comment: 1809 ships with 4.8.0 from the top of my head. Just make sure you get the right targeting pack. You can select it in the Visual Studio 2017.6 installer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for any Windows update.
Then try to re-install community edition it works